# Display non-JSON response from an API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form like this:

```
...var formdata = new FormData($("#form")[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?= base_url('whatever'); ?>',
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,...
```

My response is not in json format because it has sending file appended.
So my return from php comes like this:

```
Array
(
    [csrf] => c8871ad6103ae039e476d75e32d6b112
    [msg] => All good, information saved.
    [msg2] => (in near future) 'all files uploaded as well'
)
```

i´ve already tried read this message these ways:

```
$('#ret').html(data.responseText);
$('#ret').append(data['msg']);
$('#ret').append(data[0]['msg']);
```

What should i have to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the file content to be included in the response? Only include information that you really need, in which in this case the success message (without the HTML tags) `Artigo salvo com sucesso.`.

Comment: Try `$('#ret').append(JSON.parse(data).msg);`

Comment: i´ve just tested like you said, but it makes no difference. For now, i´m not really sending images to the server, but i will soon, so i wanna let the code prepared for that. I´ll update my question.

Comment: i have no success with JSON.parse() too. But i found a solution. We just can´t use **json** when submitting the form, but in **php** we can use `json_encode()` to return messages, but I appreciate the help, thank you very much guys.